# Mobile sub mmenu

Tags: menu

The mobile menu is working on our site, however the mobile submenu not. Could you please take on it what is the issue? website url: http://sportfogadj.hu/mesotica

Comment: Note that no one is going to visit that link and do any design/debug work for you. See [ask], but the idea is you post a [mcve] and tell us what you are trying to do and what results you get.

Comment: I am trying to use the same menu structure as it visible on desktop with mmmenu plugin on mobile. The main menu elements are visible, but the submenu isnt unfortunately. The arrows are there but you cant click on the element to open the submenu on mobile. This is what i would like to say.

Comment: [Edit] the question and tell us what you want to do, show what you have tried, and tell us what results you got.